# SMS via console on Synology NAS

Tags: linux, kernel, sms

Does anybody know is it possible to send SMS via console on Synology NAS (kernel 2.6.32.12, synology_ppc853x_410). I tried to use `gnokii` with my old S40 nokia phone. But it seems there is no `kernel-module-usbserial` for 2.6.32, i found only `kernel-module-usbserial` - 2.6.15-1. This version does not work.

When i plug in my phone i can see it using lsusb, but no device file beeing created.
`gnokii` returns:

> Telephone interface init failed: Command timed out.
>   Quitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try [usbserial.ko based on this link](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=143&t=30293)